# Documenting interfaces

Tags: c++, interface, documentation

I was wondering about how I should document an interface in my application, `IResource`. Since I'm coding an engine and not a library, I figured the documentation should give guidelines about how the implementations of the interface should be written; is that okay?

Also, could you please take a look at my interface and tell me if the comments are clear enough?

```
/**
    Interface that should be implemented by all resources. Implementing
    this interface is necessary for compatibility with the ResourceManager
    class template.

    \note Documentation of this interface includes guidelines on how
    implementations should be written.

    \see ResourceManager
                                                                              */
class IResource
{
  public:
    /**
        Loads resource data from a file. If data is already loaded,
        the function should return immediately.

        \throw std::exception Should throw on any failure to load the
        resource. If the resource is already loaded, don't throw, just
        return (as previously indicated).

        \note Access to this function should also be provided directly
        from a constructor. That constructor should catch any exceptions
        and throw them further to its caller.
                                                                              */
    virtual void loadFromFile(const std::string& file) = 0 ;
    /**
        All general guidelines from loadFromFile() also apply to this
        function. Additionally, the resource should not take possession of
        the buffer; the buffer should be safe to delete after loading.
                                                                              */
    virtual void loadFromMemory(const char* buffer, std::size_t size) = 0;
    /**
        Frees the data currently held by the resource object. Should
        return immeditelly if no data is loaded.
                                                                              */
    virtual void free() = 0;
    virtual bool isLoaded() const = 0;
};
```

---

**Edit:** Opened a related discussion.

Following mainly the conversation in the comments section of [Johann Gerell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245429/documenting-interfaces/6245629#6245629), I opened a rather lengthy thread over at programmers.stackexchange. You can check it out here:
**>** [**Single-responsibility and custom data types**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/81835)

Comment: You do know that you can't call virtual methods in a constructor?

Comment: Obviously you're not going to call `IResource::loadFromFile()` in the constructor. For example, in its constructor, `Font` will call its own implementation of that function, which compiles just fine.

Comment: What if you derive from Font and the write a new version. Then the version in Font(s) constructor will not call the correct version. Read @Johann Gerell below about dividing the `loading` and `being` a resource into different classes.

Comment: @Martin You mean like this? http://ideone.com/ni9u3 It seems to work fine.

Comment: @Martin: You can't call virtual functions in a base class constructor.  From the derived class constructor, it works just fine.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Sure the call works. But the whole concept of virtual fails to do anything useful. It is not until the constructor is complete that the virtual call mechanism has been completely initialized and you get the call to the most derived type. From the constructor you get a call to the `currently most derived` version **not** the most derived version.

Comment: @Martin: So you would eradicate non-virtual calls to virtual functions?  You're right, that isn't a virtual call.  It's a non-virtual call to a function which can also be called virtually, and that is useful.

Comment: @Paul: Yes. Exactly. Did you notice. That for the object `foo3`. That when you call From the Foo2 constructor you get "foo2" and when you call from Foo3 constructor you get "foo3". Thus there is little point in defining these functions as virtual. It would be simpler to say just initialize the object correctly in the constructor. You are gaining nothing by having the method virtual and adding uncertainty to both the designer of the implementation and the user of the interface.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: If you call from the constructor why would you want to call it again? It is basically an init() function it does not return anything. So the instructions are: 1) Call from constructor catch and discard exceptions. 2) When using check that it worked and call again if it previously failed in the constructor to make sure it worked! Sounds awfully like a 2 phase construction that I am not keen on either.

Comment: @Martin: Evidently these objects support both one-phase and two-phase construction (and so does `fstream`, which he said he's modeling his design after).

Comment: @Ben: But the streams library supports 2 phase construction via public non-virtual methods; which call private virtual methods (on internal fully constructed objects).

Comment: @Martin That's what's supposed to happen.

Comment: @Paul: Then read my other comments on why it is useless.

Comment: @Martin I'm going to write that functionality anyway, I might as well make it also available as a separate function, it's not going to cost me anything. Besides, again, I think user defined classes should try to copy the standard classes in their behavior, regardless of the language. (Btw, this is not what your original complaint was about.)

Comment: @Martin If you want to participate, I opened this new thread over at programmers.se, [Single-responsibility and custom data types](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/81835).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is much too broad for Stack Overflow, which deals with more focused coding problems.  For advice on improving working code, consider [codereview.se] instead - but do read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there!.

Answer (score 3):

Your comments should specify the contract between the user and implementer; it's not necessary to focus on the perspective of either.

The guidance about taking ownership of the buffer doesn't sound like a recommendation, it sounds like a definite requirement.  Use "will": *All access to the buffer will be performed before this function returns; the buffer may be safely freed at that time.*  Similarly: *If the resource has already been loaded, this function returns immediately.*  It's a requirement, not a recommendation.

Parameters should be documented fully.  Can the file name be a relative path?  What happens if the file does not exist?  Is unreadable due to permissions?

You should describe which exceptions may be thrown.  Catching and rethrowing exceptions is just bad design.

Using a `const char*` for non-character data is bad design, use `const void*` instead.  Document that the size is in bytes (or if not, what the units are).  Is the data in any common format, or is it unique to the subclass?

Keep per-function documentation specific to that function.  Information about interactions between multiple functions, or advice on constructor behavior of derived classes, belongs at the class level.

Use correct spelling, misspelled words distract from the content.

Comment: What do you mean that I should document which exceptions may be thrown? I don't have any special exception classes, I just use `std::exception`. The error message will be sent to the Logger and the user can read it there.

Comment: Regarding `const char*`: I actually wanted to replace that with something like `const int8*`, just haven't gotten to it yet -- should I still use `const void*`?

Comment: @Paul: Why is your interface making error-handling policy decisions for the main application?  It should provide enough information for the main program to implement a useful policy, whether that's logging, retrying, or showing only certain kinds of errors to the user.  Using `std::exception` for every error doesn't help with that.  There's an exception hierarchy for a reason.

Comment: @Paul: The interface should use `const void*`.  The implementation can use `const int*` or `RGBTRIPLE*` or whatever data type makes the most sense for processing the data.

Comment: Ben's comment about a contract is spot-on. You are targeting two audiences here, Paul: Someone who uses this class by calling one of those pure virtual methods ("user", for short), and someone who implements a class that derives from this class ("implementer", for short). The user needs to know in an abstract sense what those pure virtuals are supposed to do / allowed to do / forbidden to do. The implementer needs to know this as well, but from a slightly different point of view.

Comment: @Ben (On exceptions) I don't think the interface is making error-handling decisions for the higher levels of the application. I think it just tell you what to expect of its implementations and/or how the implementation should be written. As a side note, these exceptions never get higher than the ResourceManager.

Comment: @Ben (On `void*`) Now that I think about it, using `void*` could save me a lot of work. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 3):

You've documented the intent well, and that is a very good start.

A few things missing:

- You didn't document the arguments. They are self-obvious, but I can be a bit pedantic (ditto for doxygen).
- What does `isLoaded` do?
- Turn off the inherited documentation capability in doxygen. While your comments are valid for the interface class, they are not valid for some class that implements the interface.

Comment: I agree.  It is surprisng how non-obvious the obvious can be six months after I wrote it ;-)  Better to document something that perhaps doesn't need documenting than to not document it and later wish one had!

Answer (score 1):

Considering the code behavior of your listing instead of the doc parts, I think you should re-think the interface a bit (the other comments on the docs are good enough) in the light of the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Right now, the name `IResource` implies that the type has resource-ish behavior, but I would argue that it has no such behavior at all. Think about how you'd use this type. Most logically you would pass around reference or pointer to an `IResource`. You would then need to check if it's loaded or not with `isLoaded` before you do anything with it. Always.

What if you instead separated the two responsibilities of **loading** a resource versus **being** a resource:

```
class IResource
{
public:
    virtual SomeCommonResourceBehavior(...) = 0;

    virtual ~IResource() {}
};

class IResourceFactory
{
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<IResource> CreateFromFile(...) = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<IResource> CreateFromMemory(...) = 0;

    virtual ~IResourceFactory() {}
};
```

This way, when you see a reference or non-null pointer to an `IResource` anywhere in your code, you know that it's already created.

Also, if you cannot identify any `SomeCommonResourceBehavior` in `IResource`, then you've likely thought a bit wrong about your design.

**EDIT:** If you live in a pre-C++0x land, then `boost::unique_ptr<>` is an alternative in the factory. If boost is not an alternative, the `std::auto_ptr<>` is better than a raw pointer.

Comment: I already have something like a factory: the `ResourceManager`. Even so, in case of a failure the factory/manager must still return something (i.e. null pointer), which you'll still have to check, right? I also thought about separating loading altogether, but I figured I should copy the behavior and design of the standard objects (e.g., std::ifstream, which has `open` and `close` functions).

Comment: @Paul: Two wrongs don't add up to one right. Why would you copy the design of `std::ifstream`? Do you **need** `open` and `close`? Will you ever have any use for an IResource that isn't loaded? If that's the case, then it should probably not even be assigned in the first place. If you make a habit of having an object **created and usable** instead of **created and maybe usable** you'l save yourself many headaches, unnecessary codepaths and added complexity.

Comment: No one is voting to close this question, we're voting to move it to programmers.se, because this question is about software development process, not about the behavior of code.

Comment: @Ben: Ah, I see. I only looked at the "close (2)" string.

Comment: This calls for a much more complex discussion. I've opened a new thread over at programmers.se, [Single-responsibility and custom data types](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/81835).